# Value not changing in onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page I'm having multiviews. When the user add button in 1st view, it transfers to 2nd view.
In the 2nd view we are having full of text boxes for filling. If the enters text and tries to go away without saving. a prompt should come as keep changes or navigate away.
That functionality I had done as following code.
Whenever user do onchange of textbox in the form I'm changing the hiddenfield(taken a hidden field which indicates whether having dirty data or not) value from 0 to 1.

But I'm unable to access the hidden field value in my function.

```
var a = 0;
$(function() {
    $("input[type='text']").change(function() {
        $("#testhidden").val("1"); //changed hidden field value to 1
        a = 1; // changed a value
        console.log("a is " + a);
        console.log("testhidn value is " + $("#testhidden").val());
    });
});
$(function() {
    alert(a); //always getting "a" value as "0" even though I changed.

    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        if (a == 1) {
            $(window).on('popstate', function() {

                var hashLocation = location.hash;
                var hashSplit = hashLocation.split("#!/");
                var hashName = hashSplit[1];

                if (hashName !== '') {
                    var hash = window.location.hash;
                    if (hash === '') {
                        alert('Back button was pressed.');
                    }
                    if (a == 1) {
                        alert("a is if part 1" + a);
                    } else {
                        alert("a is else part 1" + a);
                    }
                    window.history.pushState('forward', null, '#');
                }

            });
            window.history.pushState('forward', null, '#');
            if (a == 1) {
                alert("a is if part 2" + a);
            } else {
                alert("a is else part 2" + a);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Onchange will only work when textbox is blur. You can use key press instead of onChange

Comment: in onchange Console.log showing the correct value as changed(1). But when I press Back button of web page,  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
            if (a == 1) {.......  here always value is coming as 0(zero).

Comment: Can you check on window.onbeforeunload=$(function() { });

Comment: Sorry, Here I don't want with window.obbeforeunload I had already used that in another criteria.  For my current situation window.obbeforeunload will not give me epected result(as it is having with multiviews in radstrip single menu).

Comment: Here my question is,  Why "a" value is becoming as "0" even though I changed the value in onchange ?